# Image inside DIV disappears in FireFox, Chrome, and Opera but shows up fine in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**index.html**

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>My App</TITLE>
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div id="logo"><img src="logo.jpg" /></div>
        <div id="menu">
            <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="new.php">
                <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Create New Entry">
            </FORM>
            <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="viewall.php">
                <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="View All Entries">
            </FORM>
            <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="list.php">
                <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Generate Mailing List">
            </FORM>
        </div>
        <div id="search">
            <form action="search.php" method="post">
              Search By First or Last Name:
              <input type="text" name="term" />
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

and

**style.css**

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div#logo {
    position:absolute;
    width:290px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: black;
}

div#menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 140px;
    background-color: black;
}

div#search {
    position: relative;
    width: 265px;
    left:25px;
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

It looks fine when I view in Safari, but when I view in FireFox, Chrome, or Opera the image in  disappears. It's gone completely in Chrome and Opera, and in FireFox it shows a broken link icon. I know my use of CSS here is not entirely correct, or even best practices,  but I still can't figure out why the image doesn't show up? (And what's more, why FireFox shows the broken icon)

Comment: your css and html seems fine. you might want to check again the src of your image since you saw the broken image link. you might want to clear your safari cache and see if the image is still there just to be sure.

Comment: I see the same thing in Safari and Firefox (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4xDkK/). What happens if you use an absolute path in your `<img>` (which you should always be doing anyway).

Comment: The code posted works e.g. on Firefox, when I use a URL for an existing image. If the image does not exist, Firefox just does not show the image, as usual. Please post a demo where the problem can actually be observed. Please specify, preferably with a screenshot, what you mean by “broken link icon.”

Comment: WOW, so sorry guys. I renamed the image, so it was actually logo.jpg.png (or logo.png.jpg) - I've recently switched from Windows to Mac-OSX and it's getting the better of me (also it's almost 2:00am). Sorry for wasting your time, guys but it works now.

Comment: please mark your own answer as accepted answer, thanks

Comment: I will, I have to wait 2 days before it will let me.

Comment: Mu - I was wondering what the benefits to using absolute paths are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file was named .png.jpg, so it didn't show up...newb mistake